# Getting modulus from `&`

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is modulo operator necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097534/why-is-modulo-operator-necessary)

I need help understanding how does `&` give the modulus? I am [working on an assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594208/c-program-to-determine-levels-size-of-cache) to use memory access times to determine the cache sizes. Currently I am getting wierd results for the L3 size. I think it has something to do with `&` only working well for powers of 2, or something like that? So I want to understand how it actually works

```
lengthMod = 1024/sizeof(int) - 1;
for (unsigned int k = 0; k < REPS; k++) {
    data[(k * 16) & lengthMod]++;
}
```

Will `&` always work? Or does it only work with some values? What actually happens for other values?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097534/why-is-modulo-operator-necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on the other answers, if you take the modulus of a positive number and a positive power of 2 (i.e. `a % b` where `b` is a power of 2 and `a` and `b` are positive), you can effectively replace the `%` operator with the `&` operator (and subtract 1 from b, so it becomes `a & (b - 1)`).

This is because the `&` operator does a bit-wise mask, and the result of a number mod a power of two is just going to be the lower bits of that number.

This only works when the right hand argument is a power of two and both numbers are positive. Otherwise, use the `%` operator.

Answer (score 2):

`&` is the binary "and" operator. The operator for modulus is `%`.

Comment: `&` works fine as a modulus if it's done with (2^n -1).

Answer (score 1):

& does a [bit-wise and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) operation between the two values. For modulus, you'd want to use the % operator:

```
int x = 23 % 7; // x = 2
```